# How can I persist Greasemonkey changes to a <ul> without any ids, which is getting updated constantly?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I am currently building a UserScript/Greasemonkey script for a website that provides series to watch online. They have a page with all series listed alphabetically, and are adding new series nearly daily. It’s an unordered list containing `<li>` elements.

So, the thing is, those `<li>` elements don’t have ids, but only links inside like "/series/scrubs". So I want a user to click on an eye-icon I already added using the UserScript and then mark the `<li>` entry containing that icon using `background-color: green;`.
Also I want to store those marks and restore them with every script load, probably using `GM_setValue` and `GM_getValue`.

My question is, how can I save a variable using Greasemonkey, let's say `GM_setValue("series/Scrubs", 1);` where "series/Scrubs" represents the href of a link? And how can I restore those marked `<li>` entries on script loads?

As said, I don’t have any ids to use and I can’t use `<li>`-Entry 1, Entry 2, etc, because the list will get corrupted as nearly every day there are new `<li>`s between others, etc.

TL;DR, some code for you guys to understand that:

```
<ul id='serSeries'>
   <li><a href="serie/hack-Legend-of-the-Twilight">.hack//Legend of the Twilight</a></li>
   <li><a href="serie/hack-Roots">.hack//Roots</a></li>
   <li><a href="serie/hack-Sign">.hack//Sign</a></li>
   <li><a href="serie/07-Ghost">07-Ghost</a></li>
   <li><a href="serie/10-Dinge-die-ich-an-dir-hasse">10 Dinge, die ich an dir hasse</a></li>
   <li><a href="serie/10-8-Officers-on-Duty">10-8: Officers on Duty</a></li>
   <li><a href="serie/1000-Wege-ins-Gras-zu-beissen">1000 Wege, ins Gras zu beißen</a></li>
   <li><a href="serie/101-Dalmatiner">101 Dalmatiner</a></li>
```

And here is the code I already have, to add an eye icon, and so on.

```
if (!this.GM_getValue || (this.GM_getValue.toString && this.GM_getValue.toString().indexOf("not supported")>-1)) {
    this.GM_getValue=function (key,def) {
        return localStorage[key] || def;
    };
    this.GM_setValue=function (key,value) {
        return localStorage[key]=value;
    };
    this.GM_deleteValue=function (key) {
        return delete localStorage[key];
    };
}

function countSeries(){
    return document.getElementById("serSeries").getElementsByTagName("li").length;
}

function mark(id){
    var se = countSeries()-1;
    for(var i=0; i < se; i++){
        if(i == id){
            var serie = document.getElementById("serSeries").getElementsByTagName("li")[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute("href");
            GM_setValue(serie, "1");
            document.getElementById("serSeries").getElementsByTagName("li")[i].backgroundColor = "green";
        }
    }
}

function appendViewStateOnAll() {
    var se = countSeries()-1;
    for(var i=0; i < se; i++){
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.innerHTML = "<a onclick='javascript:mark(" + i + ")' href='javascript:void(0);'> <img src='http://i.epvpimg.com/2gpcf.png'></a>";
        link.id = i;
        document.getElementById("serSeries").getElementsByTagName("li")[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].appendChild(link);
    }
}



appendViewStateOnAll();
```

Oh yeah, my function `mark(id)` isn't working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing but I'll take a moment to extrapolate what I think the intent of the question is. (No I did not read your code it is TL;DR).

Assuming one does not have control over the list markup you will have to recreate the markup each page load. This also means you will have to manage the disparity between the page's markup and your internal representation of the list data in say Greesemonkey.

First thing to do is define rules for how a [three-way merge](http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/three-way-merging-a-look-under-the-hood/240164902) should be resolved. For example if your injection includes item `(C)` in a two set list making it `(a, C, b)` and the new refresh adds a `(d)` item how do you determine where `(C)` should be injected: `(a, d, C, b)` or `(a, C, d, b)` or `(a, C, b, d)` etc. These rules are the only thing that will help you.

Secondly, you will have to develop a data model to represent this list which is compatible to be saved to Greesemonkey in some persistent storage mechanism.

Finally on each page reload you will have to construct a representation of the list, perform your three-way merge algorithm, and then replace the list with the newly merged one.

All of this is pretty advanced stuff. The bigger question and the reason I can not expand further on this answer (and hence my lack of code examples in this answer) is that you haven't spec'd out how you want this to work / look like. I think you need to think about how exactly you wish the modification of the list to look like in the end and have that clearly stated before looking for solutions.

Again, I did not read your code implementation. It is possible you have already thought this out and attempted to convey the specs via code. But for a SO question I (nor, I suspect, many other readers) would take the time to decipher it via code.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         test
// @namespace    http://stackoverflow.com
// @version      1.0
// @description  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664703/how-can-i-persist-greasemonkey-changes-to-a-ul-without-any-ids-which-is-getti
// @include      http://fiddle.jshell.net/*
// @author       zanetu
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

function toggle(event) {
    var previous = event.target.previousSibling;
    var key = previous.getAttribute('href');
    if(localStorage.getItem(key)) {
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
        previous.style.backgroundColor = '';
    }
    else {
        localStorage.setItem(key, '1');
        previous.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    }
}

function appendViewStateOnAll() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('#serSeries > li > a[href^="serie/"]');
    for(var i = links.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        var image = document.createElement('img');
        image.src = 'http://i.epvpimg.com/2gpcf.png';
        image.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        image.addEventListener('click', toggle, false);
        //may not work with internet explorer
        links[i].parentNode.insertBefore(image, links[i].nextSibling);
        //restore background color
        if(localStorage.getItem(links[i].getAttribute('href'))) {
            links[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        }
    }
}

appendViewStateOnAll();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h1ex9qd6/)